How to order the stacked bar chart by total value and subset value in ggplot?
I created the bar char as below:
mydata<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
                   total=c(24,24,24,24,22,22,22,22,22,22),
                   category=rep(c("uncomplete","complete"),5),
                   value=c(0,24,0,24,1,21,0,22,2,20))

mydata%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(id, -total),
             y=value, fill=factor(category,levels=c("uncomplete","complete"))))+
  geom_bar(position=position_stack(),stat="identity",width=0.7) + 
  geom_text(data=subset(mydata,value != 0),
            aes(label = value),position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),size=3) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.90,0.85)) +
  labs(x="Site ID",y="",fill="") +  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq (0, 30, 5), limits=c(0,30), name="Enrollment")


As you can see, the chart was ordered by total number in a descending order. However, I don't know how to let the chart be ordered by the complete number in a descending order at the same time, i.e. I'd like to order the id as 1,2,4,3,5.

Consider dplyr::arrange + forcats::fct_inorder
mydata |> 
    arrange(desc(total), desc(value)) |> 
    mutate(id = forcats::fct_inorder(as.character(id))) |>
    [...]


